# $\mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^n}]\subsetneq \mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^{n+1}}]$, in particular how to show that $\pi^{2^n}\not\in\mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^{n+1}}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How to show that $\mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^n}]\subsetneq \mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^{n+1}}]$?

I easly prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^n}]\subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^{n+1}}]$, now I want to prove that $\pi^{2^n}\not\in\mathbb{Q}[\pi^{2^{n+1}}]$ but I can't do that in an elegant way (my proof need a lot of calculations). Any suggestion?

Comment: Well where does $n$ start? At $0$? $1$?

Comment: It starts from 1

Answer (score 1):

In general, one might simply prove the following:

> If $x$ is transcendental, then $x\not\in \mathbb Q[x^2]$.

of which the proof is easy. The elements of $\mathbb Q[x^2]$ are by definition writable as $f(x^2)$ for a polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. If $x$ were in the set, then $$x=f(x^2)$$ for a polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. This contradicts that $x$ was transcendental.

Comment: $f$ does not have to be a polynomial. It is a rational function.

Comment: Why does not $f$ have to be a polynomial?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I thought the definition of $K[x]$ was the ring polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $K$ (rather than the field of rational functions). I'll admit I'm not well trained in the field - am I missing some context that implies a different definition?